# Is there a way to see 3G connection time?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, data-monitoring

I have a time-based data plan, therefore I would like to have a report of the 3G connection time (possibly with a weekly reset). However, all the application on the market reports the data usage, and not the time spent online.

Is there an app for that (for Gingerbread)?

Answer (score 1):

[My Data Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mobidia.android.mdm) app displays what you need. Check out its data pie (left-to-right swipe) and make sure Time button is pressed.

Comment: It looks like it shows the time usage per application; which is not what I want. If I have the connection established but no application is downloading data then I get incorrect results.

Answer (score -2):

I've built an app myself! This is the best I could do: it doesn't detect time connection, but shuts the device down after a delay.

[Delayed shutdown](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pesegato.delayedsd)

Comment: Isn't it clever spamming??

Comment: No, it isn't spamming. It answers the question and the relationship has been declared. Please review the [FAQ] about "promotion".

Comment: The actual app doesn't help though as far as I can tell, it just seems to shut down the device, nothing to do with data at all. How does it relate to the question..? Seems like spam to me.

Comment: It is clear that the poster made this app, so I wouldn't call it spam.